# Git workflow issue - lots of merge conflicts where files haven't been changed

Tags: git, azure-devops, merge-conflict-resolution

Here's the workflow that our teams are using:

- `main` branch which to which feature branches are squash-merged; this is handled by team A
- `big-feature` branch which is used by team B which was branched from `main`
- team B will have smaller feature-branches from `big-feature`; they are using regular fast-forward merges when they pull in their feature branches to `big-feature`

The problem: every once in a while team B wants to get the latest changes from `main` to their `big-feature`. So they do the following:

- fetch all changes from origin, and pull all changes to their local `main`
- create a `merge-with-main` branch from `big-feature`
- merge `main` into `merge-with-main`

Now, I'd expect they should only get conflicts in files that they've made changes to that were also changed on `main`. However, they currently get over 250 merge conflicts, and most (if not all) of them are in files they have not changed at all. Looking at the conflicts in Visual Studio it's clear "their" file is, for example, some initial version of the file with plenty of `NotImplementedException` instances when a stub file was committed to the `main` branch, and "incoming" is the same file with some implementation. Again - same file, clearly not changed by team B, but marked as a conflict.

Currently team B is manually resolving these conflicts (usually using the "take theirs" option), but with 250+ files it's really a hassle. What's going on here and why are these conflicts happening and what can be done to prevent / easily resolve them?

EDIT: I do believe squash-merges used on `main` might be the culprit, BUT AFAIK they should only be an issue if `big-feature` gets some changes from a feature branch from team A - then GIT would indeed "lose" track of it, since when team A commits then the source branch is, essentially, gone. BUT team B is only getting stuff directly from `main` (aside from their own changes when their working on their own feature of course), and the changes in `main` should have a source, no?

Again, **squash merges are only used when team A pulls in a small `feature-branch` to `main`**, and it's something done by the Azure DevOps PR system.

Comment: The squash merges feel like a clue here: has something in the previous history of `big-feature`  ended up with the non-squashed version of some of those changes, so that the _result_ looks the same as `main`, but the _history_ doesn't?

Comment: @Pogrindis "This should be regularly rebased // merged with main for starters." The regular merges from main are exactly what is described in the question as causing the problem.

Comment: @IMSoP merge is not `squash-merge`

Comment: @Pogrindis The description of what they're doing just says "merge main into merge-with-main". Squash merges are only mentioned with regards to merging _other_ features _onto_ main. It _could_ be that they're using squash-merge in the "merge-with-main" branch, in which case it would explain the problem, but they don't actually say so.

Comment: @IMSoP ah i was thinking of the first point, where the conflicts seem to be found - in that case would the fast-fwd that Team A do be causing some commit mismatch ?

Comment: @Pogrindis When team B is getting the changes from `main` for their `merge-with-main` branch they are NOT using squash merges. They're using regular merges.

Comment: OP, can you show what the (merged) history looks like? `gitk`, `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` or similar. It really helps to give sensible answers!

Comment: @knittl Sure; on which branch tho?

Comment: @Shaamaan all of them (pass `--all`)

Comment: @knittl That's going to be extremely long. Actually, it's extremely long even without using `--all`...

Comment: @Shaamaan maybe a pastebin link ?

Comment: @Pogrindis Hmm, that's 9412 lines of git logs. And it's a private project too and I'm not 100% certain if there isn't anything sensitive. If the relevant log was of a reasonable size I could go through it and "anonymize" anything seemingly sensitive but this is too much... :|

Comment: @Shaamaan the most recent commits should already give us a clue. If you trim it down to show the last few merges and point out which merges caused conflicts?

Comment: It looks like there are several different "main" branches. Commit `938dbaf5e` is decorated as `origin/main`, and commit `6002f179b` has message "merged main into …", yet the line is not coming from the main branch, but from somewhere else. Maybe you can simplify the graph by not showing `--all`, but `main merge-with-main big-feature` (perhaps from a specific remote). It is still difficult to give a useful answer, at the moment it is mostly guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you squash-merge, then the branch is not merged, but a new commit is created in place of the branch. If you subsequently merge the branch again, Git cannot compute the merge base and tries to re-merge (some of) the changes again, resulting in conflicts.

If you need to periodically merge a branch into another branch, do *not* use squash-merge, but a regular merge. If you use a squash-merge, you have to rebase all child-branches onto the new squashed-commit.

OPs EDIT:
Turned out that Team B did not, in fact, use regular merges when updating their `bit-feature` branch with the code from `main` and have been using squash-merges. Thus they violated the last paragraph of this answer causing all manner of issues down the line.

Comment: Agree for regular merge, or rebase if you need to retain all commits from `main`

Comment: Just to be clear, the question currently only mentions squash merges for other tasks going into main. The "merge main into merge-with-main" step (and then merging that into big-feature) don't actually specify what options they're using. But if they _are_ using squash merge for either of those, you're right that it would cause the problem described.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what's happening here. Team B isn't merging individual feature branches from team A to their `big-feature` branch, but rather they're taking the whole `main` branch. So... squash merges SHOULDN'T have an effect, AFAIK.

Comment: @Shaamaan According to your own answer which was posted half an hour later, this is exactly what's happening here :)

Comment: @knittl Aye - I don't know why, but I thought this was about quashes being used on `main` - which in and of itself isn't a problem. I'll accept this.